# How to load Chosen jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

Maybe I'm too ignorant, but I just can't find a way to load the Chosen plug-in into my html. I've seen previous questions and they load .js and .css files, but I don't find them in the new versions. How do I load it now?

Comment: It's called Chosen, here's the link: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you have to include the `jQuery` library, get it from [here](http://code.jquery.com/), then you'll have to add the `chosen.js` file, downloaded from [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), and finally you have to turn your `select` HTML element into "*chosen*" element, your HTML code should look like this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/chosen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#element").chosen();
 });
</script>
```

This is the default usage of `chosen.js`, you can however specify many other option, but it is better to read the documentation.

Download the latest version of `chosen.js` from [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/tag/v1.1.0).

Comment: I had already loaded jQuery and the script as you pointed, just couldn't find the chosen.js file, Thanks @bodi0